# fitting an equation to cross-section data

Tags: matlab

I am trying to fit an equation to the data, i am using polyfit but it is not close enough. I also dont have curve fitting toolbox. Here is the code and picture:

```
p2 = polyfit(xDat,zDat,2);
f2 = polyval(p2,xDat);


figure;
plot(xDat,zDat,'.r');
hold on
plot(xDat,f2,'*b');
```

[image]

Red dots is data and Blue points is the fit.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40160257/3372061) on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a second order (quadratic) polynomial:

```
p2 = polyfit(xDat,zDat,2);
```

I suggest testing higher order polynomials as in:

```
p2 = polyfit(xDat,zDat,3);
p2 = polyfit(xDat,zDat,4);
p2 = polyfit(xDat,zDat,5);
```

and see if one of those might work.